# Cleaning a dataset in python

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can translate this text file into csv with python. below, the code I tried that does not work. I want to subdivide into four columns: Date, Time, Number, Message. thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code!

Comment: "Translate this text into csv" is a very unclear problem statement. Provide a [MCVE] and read [ask], please.

Comment: could you provide the text file here instead of the picture?

Comment: And don't forget to tell what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can do this using Regular expressions (Regex). If you're new to regex try [regexone.com](http://regexone.com) it's a great beginners guide!

The regex below finds the parts of the string which match the specified criteria. And then takes the bits in the parentheses and assigns them to the variable 'match' which is then called later.

```
# First import pandas and the regex module
import pandas as pd
import re

#Define filepaths
InputFilePath =
OutputFilePath = 

# Read the .txt file into a string
data = open(InputFilePath)
string = data.read()
data.close()

#Split seperate lines into list of strings
splitstring = string.splitlines()

# For each list item find the data needed (with regex or indexing) 
# and assign to a dictionary

df = {}
for i in range(len(splitstring)):
    match = re.search(r'(.*) \xc3\xa0 (.*) - (.*): (.*)',splitstring[i])
if match is None:
    match = re.search(r'(.*) \xc3\xa0 (.*) - ()(.*)',splitstring[i])
if match is None:
    line = {
'Date' : "",
'Time' : "",

'Number' : "",
'Text' : ""}
else:    
    line = {
'Date' : match.group(1),
'Time' : match.group(2),

'Number' : match.group(3),
'Text' : match.group(4)}
df[i] = line

# Convert dictionary to pandas dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df).T

# Finally send to csv
dataframe.to_csv(OutputFilePath)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, here is the error that it generates me : ------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-43a1f0fdf7c6> in <module>()
      8     line = {
      9     'Date' : splitstring[i][:10],
---> 10     'Time' : match.group(1),
     11     'Number' : match.group(2),
     12     'Text' : match.group(3)}

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'     and NameError: name 'filepath' is not defined

Comment: Firstly you have to define filepath as the path where you want your csv

Comment: The regex expression that I wrote doesn't match every line in your dataset (e.g the first line doesn't have a number). That's why the variable match is coming up as a 'NoneType' Object for these lines. Try and adjust the regex so that it matches every line of your data. I don't have your dataset so can't do it myself

Comment: OK understood. I will come back to you. Thank you

Comment: Hi, if you could give me an email address so that I can send you the file. otherwise, it really heats me up.